# Wrong model item passed (with partial view)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, partial-views

I am working with ASP.NET MVC 2 and VS 2010. and I have two views: 
**view1** is for creating a record in the database. 
**view2** is for listing the data from the database.

I am trying to *merge* those views so that I could see them in one .aspx file by using 4 .aspx files: 
Views/Shared/view1.aspx 
Views/Shared/view2.aspx 
Views/Home/index.aspx (here goes the code for the partial view) 
Views/Shared/ChartLayout.Master (this one is not essential at all, it's just for CSS testing)

**Error**: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet`1[BookingApp.Models.BookingTableSet]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'BookingApp.Models.BookingTableSet'.

Everything works fine if I leave view1 blank.

Here's my code,

**Index.aspx**:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
<asp:Content ID="indexTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
Home Page
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="indexContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<h2><%= Html.Encode(ViewData["Message"]) %></h2>
<div style="float:left"><%Html.RenderPartial("view1"); %></div>
<div style="float:left"><%Html.RenderPartial("view2"); %></div>
<div style="clear:both">
</div>  
</asp:Content>
```

**view1.aspx**:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"      Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<BookingApp.Models.BookingTableSet>"  %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
Create
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<h2>Create</h2>
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Id) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Quality) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Quality) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Quality) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsBooked) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.IsBooked) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsBooked) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataBooked) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DataBooked) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataBooked) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.TimeBooked) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TimeBooked) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TimeBooked) %>
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
<% } %>
<div>
    <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

I bet that is has something to do with the Inheritance but I have no idea what. 
Thanks for any help.

**EDIT**
Site.Master:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
<link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="page">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="title">
            <h1>My MVC Application</h1>
        </div>              
        <%-- %> <div id="logindisplay">
            <% Html.RenderPartial("LogOnUserControl"); %>
        </div> %>            
        <div id="menucontainer">          
           <%-- %> <ul id="menu">              
                <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")%></li> 
                <li><%: Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")%></li> 
            </ul> --%>          
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "Id")] BookingTableSet movieToCreate)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View();

        _db.AddToBookingTableSets(movieToCreate);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

## **EDIT2**:

Basically what I have are these two tutorials meerged together: 
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/movie-database/create-a-movie-database-application-in-15-minutes-with-asp-net-mvc-cs

http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/asp-net-mvc-and-the-templated-partial-view-death-to-ascx/

Maybe this will help to understand what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the model explicitly like Html.RenderPatial("view1", Model.BookingSet);

where BookingSet is the model required by view1

The view data dictionary passed to the controllers view just has one model and the aspx for view1 is expecting a model of different type

Comment: I've tried it - compiler doesn't recognize it. 

I know that it is something very easy but this is my first time with MVC and only second time coding with ASP.NET, so some things just look weird to me.

Comment: Could you share your master page code and also the code from your controller where you are returning the view

Comment: I've edited my question with the code. 
I had to comment <div id="logindisplay"> and <ul id="menu"> because they also had some errors, though as I mentioned before - partial view was working if view1 was blank.

Comment: It's only a return: 
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_db.BookingTableSets);
        }

Comment: then in you Index.aspx do Html.RenderPartial("view1", Model);

Comment: It gave the exact same error:
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet`1[BookingApp.Models.BookingTableSet]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'BookingApp.Models.BookingTableSet'.

That's the thing, I've tried >30 possible and not really possible methods to put a model but it just doesn't work.

Comment: Ideally you should never have to include aspx in aspx. In your case Index and view1 both are inheriting from site.master which has html, head and body tag. So you will end up with html tag within html tag

Comment: What is the type of _db.BookingTableSets?

Comment: I think you are passing a collection of BookingTableSet as your model whereas your view is expecting only one BookTableSet

Comment: in your Index action try return View(_db.BookingTableSets[0]). If your want to pass a collection then change your view to Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<ICollection<BookingApp.Models.BookingTableSet>>"

Comment: It's a ObjectSet<BookingTableSet> if that's what you asked. 

Maybe in this case it's easier to pass two .ascx views into the main .aspx view? It's my first time with views and I really have no idea. 
Thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: You can do a loop over your collection in index.aspx..see answer below

Answer (score 0):

In Index.aspx do

```
     <% foreach(BookingTableSet set in Model)
     {
        Html.Render("view1", set);
     }%>
```

Again remember that your view1 also has a masterpage which has html tag in it and so does Index.aspx. This is not good html even though the browser will render it. You should create a partial view for view1 and then include that partial view in your view(Index.aspx)